# Checkbox property DefaultChecked in reactjs not working with states updated by radio button

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

On the bases of the value of radio button(html mention below) I want to mark checkbox as checked or unchecked. Below is my code which is not working.

Thank you for your  suggestions.

Radio button

```
    <Input
      type="radio"
      name="radio1"
      value="No"
      defaultChecked
      onChange={ (e) => {
                         this.setState({
                                        auto_registration: e.target.value
                                       })
                        } } />
    <Input
      type="radio"
      name="radio1"
      value="Yes"
      onChange={ (e) => {
                         this.setState({
                                        auto_registration: e.target.value
                                       })
                        } } />
```

Checkbox

```
<Input
      type="checkbox"
      defaultChecked={ this.state.auto_registration && this.state.auto_registration == "Yes" ? true : false }
      disabled={ this.state.auto_registration && this.state.auto_registration == "Yes" ? true : false } />
```

Answer (score 3):

`defaultChecked` property is only used on initial render. If you want to have a controlled checked input, se the checked property instead

```
<Input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={ this.state.auto_registration && this.state.auto_registration == "Yes" ? true : false }
      disabled={ this.state.auto_registration && this.state.auto_registration == "Yes" ? true : false } />
```